# consuming web api in html page using jquery ajax call. Showing error

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Error : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

http://achecker.ca/checkacc.php?uri=equipprogramming.com&id=c23496926e9620bb0ab4b3c4443ec070ccb80d0b&output=html&guide=508&offset=0

(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'missing).

Comment: Paste that `error` in `google.com`, you will get thousands of answers. You need to do some research, and come up with specific question..

Answer (score 0):

You need to

A) change the configuration of your webserver to allow CORS by adding

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

See http://enable-cors.org/server.html to see how

or B)

Avoid doing Cross-origin-requests as this may be a security risk. I suggest you read up on what this implies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thanks Emanuel Ey, but I dont have any webconfig file. So how to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin=True

Comment: That will depend on what webserver you are using. I've edited my answer to add a link with instructions for several webservers

Comment: @AvinashNarnaware:  Any success?